# How to work with multiple groups of radio buttons in Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have this component that basically loops over an array of questions, each with choices and onSubmit, I'd like to capture the question's index as well as the user's selected answer. After retrieving the list of questions from the server, I'm generating an array containing objects, each with a `quesiton` and `answer` property and then using that to initialize the form. My implementation is similar to the following...

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";

const questions = [
  {
    question: "What is 1 + 1?",
    choices: [
      { option: "A", answer: 2 },
      { option: "B", answer: 3 },
      { option: "C", answer: 4 },
      { option: "D", answer: 8 },
    ],
  },
    {
    question: "What is 3 * 3?",
    choices: [
      { option: "A", answer: 2 },
      { option: "B", answer: 3 },
      { option: "C", answer: 4 },
      { option: "D", answer: 8 },
    ],
  },
];

class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
    };
  }

  userSelection(length) {
    const initialValues = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      initialValues.push({ question: i, answer: "" });
    }

    return initialValues;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Fetch all the questions and set state
    this.setState({ questions });
  }

  render() {
    const { questions } = this.state;
    const userSelection = {answers: this.userSelection(questions.length)};
    console.log(userSelection);

    return (
      <Formik enableReinitialize={true} initialValues={userSelection}>
        {({ values, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {questions.map((q, index) => (
              <div className="card" key={index}>
                <div className="card-header">Question {index + 1}</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h6 className="card-title">{q.question}</h6>
                  <div className="question-choices px-2">
                    {q.choices.map((choice) => (
                      <div className="form-check" key={choice.option}>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          id={choice.option}
                          className="form-check-input"
                          name={`values.answers[${index}].answer`}
                          value={choice.option}
                          checked={
                            values.answers && values.answers[index]
                              ? values.answers[index].answer ===
                                choice.option
                              : false
                          }
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          onBlur={handleBlur}
                        />
                        <label
                          className="form-check-label clickable"
                          htmlFor={choice.option}
                        >
                          <span className="mr-2">{choice.option} )</span>{" "}
                          {choice.answer}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              disabled={isSubmitting}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}

export default Questions;
```

When I click on a radio button, I'd like for the property answer for each question to be set to the selected value but this is not working. I don't know what exactly I'm doing wrong. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is wrong `name` attribute for `input` because you do not have `values` in your data model.

Just remove it from the name:

`answers[${index}].answer` instead of `values.answers[${index}].answer`

```
<input
  type="radio"
  id={choice.option}
  className="form-check-input"
  name={`answers[${index}].answer`}
  value={choice.option}
  checked={
    values.answers && values.answers[index]
      ? values.answers[index].answer === choice.option
      : false
  }
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
/>;
```

Here is working example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-brown-xemxi?file=/src/App.js:1876-2502)

Comment: Thanks. That kinda works but now when I click on the choices for the next question, it checks the radios for the first one. Check out this blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-axqcjy

Comment: Can you check this blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aecdh8?file=Questions.js

Comment: It's doing the same thing. The radio for the first question is getting checked and the answer is being populated but question two is not behaving as should. The radio buttons in question two are changing question one's answer.

Comment: Can you change the `key` attribute on answers `div` like this `<div className="form-check" key={q.question + choice.option}>` and key for question

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-night-2uj9f

Comment: The issue with clicking the labels was in the naming so I changed the input id to `{q.question + choice.option}` and the label's htmlFor attribute to `{q.question + choice.option}` and now clicking on the labels works fine. Thank you mate.

Comment: Still on Formik, there is this file upload example that I found on the web but inside the formik `values` object, the file is an empty object. I can't figure it out - https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-file-input-with-validation-forked-r5jqg?file=/src/App.js:342-386